# Entering program's internal memory area

Tags: c, memory-management

Is there any way (OS-independent) for accessing an arbitrary process's virtual memory with i/o access?
Alternatively.. a way to launch such process in shared memory instance.

(Isn't that the way [Cheat Engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/) works? Some sort of IPC as far as I can tell..)

Comment: You can access the virtual memory of your own process very easily.

Comment: Edited question to explicitly clarify that it relates to any process.

Comment: Programs that act like debuggers can access another process's memory, but if the I/O is memory mapped, like DMA, then you need to call OS functions to lock memory pages and translate their addresses from virtual to physical addresses.

Answer (score 2):

A process can be attached to another process in such a way that it has access to that process's memory.

It is used for debugging programs.

A debugger needs to be attached to the process being debugged, and needs to be able to read any memory data, break execution, edit memory data, inject code, etc.

Cheat Engine just re-purposes these debugger functions in order to cheat in games.

Profilers also use this to see who is consuming what resources.